# Can a thumbnail of an animated gif be animated?

Tags: post-thumbnails, images

I have an animated gif I want to show in two places, having two different sizes.

I am creating two sizes in my functions.php, using

```
add_image_size( 'small-feature', 500, 300 );
add_image_size( 'gallery-thumb', 120, 9999 );
```

If the uploaded file is 500 x 300 px, it will keep the animation, as it no resizing happens. If the image is to be resized, the animation is lost.

Is there a way I can resize these images and still keep the animation in the original .gif file?

Comment: Please take a look at the resulting file format for the thumbnail.

Comment: Yes!
There's a plugin called [EWWW Image Optimizer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ewww-image-optimizer/). When compressing animated GIFs and creating the thumbnails will retain the animation.
Proof: [Original Image](https://cdromance.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/5543screenshot4.gif). The animated [150x150 thumbnail](https://cdromance.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/5543screenshot4-150x150.gif).

Answer (score 2):

According to [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718491/resize-animated-gif-file-without-destroying-animation), there is a program called imagemagick that might do this for you server side but it would probably be outside of WordPress. Otherwise, it looks like you have to shrink every frame and then put it all back together.